# Jquery append doesn't work with <tr> tag

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, append

I'm trying to append to this code:

```
<table class="stores" border="1" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>Stores:</tr>
</table>
```

This code, which I want to work, doesn't:

```
$('.stores').append('<tr>Test</tr>');
```

This one does work:

```
$('.stores').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Can you say why?

P.S. Not sure it matters but I'm working under WordPress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not valid HTML. You're missing the `<td>`

Works fine when you change the markup : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/XHvVk/

```
$('.stores').append('<tr><td>Test</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't have text between tr-tags. Try this:

```
$('.stores').append('<tr><td>Test</td></tr>');
```